# JavaScript Trying to alternate backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the background image to alternate. It was working previously but now something is off. Right now the background is the same one as set by CSS, I want to change that to alternate it.

```js
var widthOfBrowser = window.innerWidth;
var heightOfBrowser = window.innerHeight;
var hideImage;
var timeInterval = 20000;
var time = 5000;
var changeNavBar = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var T1;
var T2;
var T3;
var intervalMain;
var text;
var parent;
var child1;
var child2;
var valueHidePadding;
var mobileTwo;
var desktopView;
var obj3;
var obj1;
var obj2;

if (widthOfBrowser < 500) {
  hideImage = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  hideImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
  parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  child1 = document.getElementById("removeMobile1");
  child2 = document.getElementById("removeMobile2");
  parent.removeChild(child1);
  parent.removeChild(child2);
} else {
  intervalMain = setInterval(function() {
    putTogether()
  }, timeInterval);

  function putTogether() {
    T1 = setTimeout(function() {
      image1()
    }, time); //after 5 seconds the function alternatingImages1to2 will be executed
    time += 5000;
    T2 = setTimeout(function() {
      image2()
    }, time); //after 10 seconds the function alternatingImages2to3 will be executed
    time += 10000;
    T3 = setTimeout(function() {
      image3()
    }, time);
    time = 5000;

  }

}

function image1() {
  obj1 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  obj1 = obj1.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
}

function image2() {

  obj2 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  obj2 = obj2.style.backgroundImage = "url('')"; //placeholder img


}

function image3() {
  obj3 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  obj3 = obj3.style.backgroundImage = "url('')"; //placeholder image
}

// Related css
```

```css
body {
  background: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/126/387606063_408c203f6c_b.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /* This is to set the background */
}
```

Comment: What's that `\`` doing after `var intervalMain;\`` ?

Comment: thanks wow how did I not notice that, thank you

Comment: When I try your example the image disappears after 20 seconds, like it should. Since you don't have any URLs in `image1()`, `image2()`, and `image3()`, nothing takes its place. What are you expecting to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the image URLs:

```
obj1.style.backgroundImage = "url('')"
```

Should be:

```
obj1.style.backgroundImage = "url('path/to/image.jpg')"
```